# Generating a new web-page template and adding multiple new elements with pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

So, I am trying to generate a web-page template with JavaScript according to user specified values. I tested it with just `background-color` and made it working.

I wanted **to add a bunch of new elements**. Also I need **to add style to each elements**. I am able to do it with the current code.

But the problem I am having is that the code is becoming **"TOO HARD TO READ"**. And I don't think I'm writing clean code. So, the question I have for you fellow Dev's is that is there another way to achieve this - with just **pure JavaScript (vanilla JS)**. That is:-

- To add specific elements separately.
- To style those elements also separately.

EDIT: I have updated the finished project. It's readable. But I would like to **NOT** use `document.write` as it is wasting time for me to read and understand. I would get stuck if I wanted to edit it later on... Please any other way you can suggest..

```js
function renderForm(){
 var bgc = document.getElementById("bgcolor").value;
 var nc = document.getElementById("ncolor").value;
 var tc = document.getElementById("tcolor").value;
 var nm = document.getElementById("ntext").value;
 window.alert("Confirm To NUKE!");
 var generateTemplate = window.open("","_self");
 generateTemplate.document.write('<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Incoming Nuke!</title></head><body style="background-color:'+bgc+'">');
 generateTemplate.document.write('<style>:root{ --main-nuke-color: '+nc+'; --main-text-color: '+tc+'; } .box{ position:absolute; display: block; height: 500px; width: 500px; animation-name: drop;animation-duration: 4s; animation-iteration-count: infinite;animation-direction:normal; animation-timing-function: linear; } .nhead{position: relative; display: block; height: 450px; width: 200px;border-radius: 50%; top: 20%; left: 15%; background-color:var(--main-nuke-color); transform: rotate(45deg); z-index: 9; } .nend{ position: absolute;display: block; width: 0; height: 0; border-top: 100px solid transparent;border-right: 100px solid  var(--main-nuke-color); border-bottom: 100px solid transparent; top: 20%; left: 50%; transform: rotate(-45deg); } .ntailleft{position: absolute; display: block; width: 0; height: 0; border-top: 80px solid transparent; border-right: 80px solid  var(--main-nuke-color);border-bottom: 80px solid transparent; top: 3%; left: 53%; transform:rotate(0deg); } .ntailright{ position: absolute; display: block; width: 0;height: 0; border-top: 80px solid transparent; border-right: 80px solid var(--main-nuke-color); border-bottom: 80px solid transparent; top: 23%; left:73%; transform: rotate(270deg); } .ntailmiddle{ position: absolute; display:block; width: 0; height: 0; border-top: 80px solid transparent; border-right:80px solid  var(--main-nuke-color); border-bottom: 80px solid transparent;top: 10%; left: 65%; transform: rotate(135deg); } .text{ position: absolute;display: block; font-size: 90px; transform: rotate(-90deg); top: 35%; left:-62%; color: var(--main-text-color); word-wrap: break-word; white-space: nowrap;  width: 430px;  overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; }div.text:hover { overflow: visible; }@keyframes drop{ 0%{ top: -50%; left: 100%; } 100%{ top: 100%; left: -50%; } }</style>'); 
 generateTemplate.document.write('<div class="box"><div class="nhead"><div class="text">'+nm+'</div></div><div class="nend"></div><div class="ntailleft"></div><div class="ntailright"></div><div class="ntailmiddle"></div></div>'); 
 generateTemplate.document.write('</body></html>');
} 

function initMyEvents(){
  document.getElementById("nuked").onclick = renderForm;
}

window.onload = initMyEvents;
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Geo&display=swap');
body{
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #cccccc;
 font-family: 'Geo', sans-serif;
 font-size: 30px;
}
.customizerTable{
 margin: auto;

}
.button{
 border: none;
  align-items: center;
   background-color: rgb(204,204,204);
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), -2px -2px 4px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
   border-radius: 50px;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 5%;
    padding: 5%;
  width: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.button:active{
 box-shadow: -2px -2px 4px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset, 2px 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset;
}
.card{
 border: none;
  align-items: center;
   background-color: rgb(204,204,204);
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), -2px -2px 4px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
   border-radius: 50px;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   margin: auto;
   padding: 10%;
  width: 100%;
}
.customizeField{
 /*TEST 1*/
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   /*TEST 1*/
}
.textbutton{
 border: none;
  align-items: center;
   background-color: rgb(204,204,204);
    box-shadow: -2px -2px 4px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset, 2px 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset;
   border-radius: 50px;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 5%;
    padding: 5%;
  width: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<table class="customizeField">
   <tr>
    <td>
     <div class="card">
      <div>Customize</div>
      <table class="customizerTable">
       <tr>
        <td>Background color:</td>
        <td><input type="color" id="bgcolor" name="bgcolor" value="#80ccff" class="button"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Nuke color:</td>
        <td><input type="color" id="ncolor" name="ncolor" value="#262626" class="button"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Text color:</td>
        <td><input type="color" id="tcolor" name="tcolor" value="#e6e600" class="button"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Enter Nuke Code:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="ntext" name="ntext" maxlength="6" class="textbutton" value="#NUKED"></td>
       </tr>
      </table>
     </div>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <a type="submit" value="Submit it!" class="button" id="nuked">NUKE!</a>
    </td>
   </tr>  
  </table>
```

Comment: To me, your code looks quite short and very easy to read. There are some minor best-practices that could be implemented, but nothing stands out as in serious need of improvement. Is this the *actual* full code you're using that you find too ugly?

Comment: Actually I have to start adding a lot more elements. I really needed to understand this before I re-code my entire script.

Comment: It's good to learn first, no? So, I can choose the best way possible.

Comment: Per the rules here, you should implement the code (even if it's ugly) for the multiple elements in order for it to be reviewed. It's not clear what you want with multiple elements either

Comment: Hey, sorry I'm late but. I didn't want to bother you since I actually completed this. But I would like to know if you could tell me another way to do this without using `document.write'. It really makes my code hard to edit, later. It's not a big project. But I want to know this. I don't like how I added all those CSS styles. If I wanted to change it, I might break everything. 

I want to share this code for any code newbie to understand. But right now it is not worth it, I guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue that will make your code readable is to use *template literals* instead of `'` and `"` string literals when constructing the HTML. Template literals allow for the writing of *readable, multiline* strings, as well as easy interpolation. For example, the following line:

```
document.write('<style>:root{ --someVar: ' + someValue + '}</style><div>foo</div><div>bar</div>');
```

can be written as:

```
document.write(`
  <style>
    :root {
      --someVar: ${someValue}
    }
  </style>
  <div>foo</div>
  <div>bar</div>
`);
```

By following this sort of pattern, your `document.write` strings become *much* nicer to read and comprehend.

Other possible improvements:

It's good to use informative variable names that give you a good sense of what the variable holds on sight. For example, if someone else saw the line

```
var tc = document.getElementById("tcolor").value;
```

They probably wouldn't have any idea what `tc` is supposed to be except by examining where else the `tc` variable is referenced.

Your current method of getting the value of each input separately is a bit WET, too. You might consider selecting *all* inputs in the document (or form) at once, somehow. One option is to use `querySelectorAll`, map each element to its value, then destructure into the variables:

```
const [
  backgroundColor,
  nukeColor,
  textColor,
  nukeCode,
] = [...document.querySelectorAll('input')].map(input => input.value);
```

That's short and reasonably elegant, but not entirely maintainable if you ever decide to remove/add an input or change their order. You could iterate over the inputs and put their values into an object instead:

```
const inputValues = {};
for (const input of document.querySelectorAll('input')) {
  inputValues[input.name] = input.value;
}
```

Once the user presses submit, they're presented "Confirm to nuke", but don't have any choice in the matter. Consider using `window.confirm` instead of `window.alert` to give them the option to cancel (or change the wording to "Nuke launching...").

You create a window with `window.open` and put into a variable named `generateTemplate`. That's a confusingly odd name for a `window` object - consider something like `newWindow` instead.

Creating a new window like this is a bit odd. If it's required for some reason, that's fine, but *usually* it would make more sense to stay on the current page and replace the necessary content.

It's usually a good idea to avoid assigning to `onclick` properties, because they only permit a *single* listener - if another script assigns to the `onclick` too, the earlier listener will be lost. Best to use `addEventListener` instead - even if you don't plan on adding additional listeners, it's a good habit to get into.

Same sort of thing for `window.onload`. Though, it'd probably be better to listen for the `DOMContentLoaded` listener, which doesn't wait for images and other media to load first - or, even better, have the initial JS run after the page is loaded to avoid having to handle any such events - either put the script in a separate file and give it the `defer` attribute:

```
<script src="myscript.js" defer>
```

Or put it at the bottom of the `<body>`:

```
  ... page content
  <script src="myscript.js">
</body>
```

`document.write` is weird to use nowadays. Better to use more trustworthy and modern methods of DOM manipulation, like with `document.createElement` or `insertAdjacentHTML` to insert elements. To set the document title, assign to `myWindow.document.title`.

Inside the created window, creating so much CSS dynamically is odd. If possible, use a *separate file* for the bulky CSS and link to it. This way, all you have to do dynamically is set the CSS variables:

```
myWindow.document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">');
myWindow.document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
    <style>
    :root {
      background-color: ${inputValues.backgroundColor};
      --main-nuke-color: ${inputValues.nukeColor};
      --main-text-color: ${inputValues.textColor}
    }
    </style>
`);
```

All together, you get:

```js
function renderNuke() {
  const inputValues = {};
  for (const input of document.querySelectorAll('input')) {
    inputValues[input.name] = input.value;
  }
  if (!window.confirm("Confirm To NUKE!")) return;
  const newWindow = window.open("", "_self");
  newWindow.document.title = 'Incoming Nuke!';
  newWindow.document.body.innerHTML = `
    <style>
    :root {
      background-color: ${inputValues.backgroundColor};
      --main-nuke-color: ${inputValues.nukeColor};
      --main-text-color: ${inputValues.textColor}
    }

    .box {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    animation-name: drop;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: normal;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
  }

  .nhead {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 450px;
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 20%;
    left: 15%;
    background-color: var(--main-nuke-color);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    z-index: 9;
  }

  .nend {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 100px solid transparent;
    border-right: 100px solid var(--main-nuke-color);
    border-bottom: 100px solid transparent;
    top: 20%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }

  .ntailleft {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 80px solid transparent;
    border-right: 80px solid var(--main-nuke-color);
    border-bottom: 80px solid transparent;
    top: 3%;
    left: 53%;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  .ntailright {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 80px solid transparent;
    border-right: 80px solid var(--main-nuke-color);
    border-bottom: 80px solid transparent;
    top: 23%;
    left: 73%;
    transform: rotate(270deg);
  }

  .ntailmiddle {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 80px solid transparent;
    border-right: 80px solid var(--main-nuke-color);
    border-bottom: 80px solid transparent;
    top: 10%;
    left: 65%;
    transform: rotate(135deg);
  }

  .text {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    font-size: 90px;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    top: 35%;
    left: -62%;
    color: var(--main-text-color);
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 430px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }

  div.text:hover {
    overflow: visible;
  }

  @keyframes drop {
    0% {
      top: -50%;
      left: 100%;
    }

    100% {
      top: 100%;
      left: -50%;
    }
  }
  </style>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="nhead">
      <div class="text">${inputValues.nukeCode}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="nend"></div>
    <div class="ntailleft"></div>
    <div class="ntailright"></div>
    <div class="ntailmiddle"></div>
  </div>
  `;
}

document.getElementById("nuked").addEventListener('click', renderNuke);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Geo&display=swap');
body {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  font-family: 'Geo', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.customizerTable {
  margin: auto;
}

.button {
  border: none;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), -2px -2px 4px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  border-radius: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top: 5%;
  padding: 5%;
  width: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.button:active {
  box-shadow: -2px -2px 4px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset, 2px 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset;
}

.card {
  border: none;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), -2px -2px 4px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  border-radius: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10%;
  width: 100%;
}

.customizeField {
  /*TEST 1*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  /*TEST 1*/
}

.textbutton {
  border: none;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
  box-shadow: -2px -2px 4px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset, 2px 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset;
  border-radius: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top: 5%;
  padding: 5%;
  width: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<table class="customizeField">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="card">
        <div>Customize</div>
        <table class="customizerTable">
          <tr>
            <td>Background color:</td>
            <td><input name="backgroundColor" type="color" value="#80ccff" class="button"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Nuke color:</td>
            <td><input name="nukeColor" type="color" value="#262626" class="button"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Text color:</td>
            <td><input name="textColor" type="color" value="#e6e600" class="button"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Enter Nuke Code:</td>
            <td><input name="nukeCode" class="textbutton" value="#NUKED"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a type="submit" value="Submit it!" class="button" id="nuked">NUKE!</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```